# Chance for getting M samples from each of N Groups given S samples.

Tags: probability

How would I calculate the following:

Chance for getting $M$ samples from each of $N$ Groups given $S$ samples when drawing one by one with replacement.

I want to plot the probability for $M=1$ given Sample sizes $S =1:100$ for $N=10$ Grops.

Example:

I draw one sample and note the group it belong to. $N=10$ groups. (assume equal size of each group)
I continue to draw samples $S=50$ times and would now like to know, what is the chance I get more or $M=1$ from each of the 10 groups.

I want to do it generic for $N,M,S$

Does it make sense?

[image]

Comment: I need some clarification as to what you mean.  Can you elaborate, possibly with a small example?

Comment: added an example

Comment: Thanks, do you want M being exactly 1 or are you happy selecting more than one sample from a given group?

Comment: more than M samples are okay.

Comment: I can't see any way past doing a rather crude brute force attempt on the multinomial distribution:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution.  We could suppose the first $M N$ samples were used to fill out the $N$ groups but there'd be no way to go further from that point without double counting.  I think the best way to go from here is to look up existing research or wait until someone who knows how to do it is online :(

Comment: if its easier for just M = 1 and able to plot the image from the textbook, im okay with that.

Comment: The one way I can think for that is 1 - prob(exactly 1 group isn't sampled) - prob(exactly 2 groups isn't sampled) ... - prob(exactly N - 1 groups isn't sampled)

Answer (score 0):

If we are working specifically for $M = 1$, we can do the following

$$P(1, N, S) = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \left(\begin{array}{c} N \\ i \end{array}\right) \left(\frac{N-i}{N}\right)^S P(1, N-i, S) $$

Edit:  I think I fixed it, I needed to multiply by $P(1, N-i, S)$.  So we need to calculate it recursively in a way too....

Alternatively we can do inclusion/exclusion to avoid the recursion.  1 - prob(1 fails) + prob(2 fails) - prob(3 fails) ...  I'm getting too tired to think so I'll just leave this here and see what someone else says.

Comment: This gets us numbers much more like the graph you posted above so I get the feeling this is fine.

Comment: Hm I'm getting negative values for $S = 11$.  Let me find where the problem is....